# Size of object through Multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class C which inherits from two classes A and B .These classes have private member named i and as far i know private members wont be inherited . when i print out the size of the derived object i get the size as 12 but i expected it to be 4 as the members wont be inherited .why the size is shown as 12 and not 4 ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    private:
        int i;
    public:
        A():i(1){}
};


class B
{
    private:
        int i;
    public:
        B():i(2){}
};


class C : private B,private A
{

    int i;
    public:
    C():i(3){}

    public:
    void disp()
    {
        //cout<<A::i<<endl;
        cout <<"i = "<< i<<endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    C c1;
    cout <<"sizeof c object = "<< sizeof(c1)<< endl;
    c1.disp();
    return 0;
}

output :
sizeof c object = 12
i = 3
```

Comment: Private members are inherited. You just can't access their names.

Comment: private members are inherited too. but they can't be accessed without parent class' methods

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a simple misconception of `private` inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far I know private members wont be inherited.

But they are.

Private members are part of the derived class, but are not *accessible* by it. This explain why your derived class has a size of 12.